# Converter DATA dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss para aaaa/mm/dd

Tags: sql, conversão-de-tipo, sql-server-2012

Tenho uma data no seguinte formato 14/12/2015 00:00:00 e preciso converter para 2015-12-14 como eu posso fazer isso no `SQL`?

Comment: Você quer fazer isso na instrução sql ou na sua aplicação?

Comment: Você precisa especificar mais sua pergunta.

Comment: Qual o banco de dados que está utilizando?

Comment: Estou utilizado SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Lilloh, ja tem sua resposta ?

Comment: @Lilloh Você negativou minha resposta? por quê?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faça isso pequeno padawan:

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, dataSistema, 103), 102) AS novaData
```

Exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2173d/2

Na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187928%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) tem alguns exemplos e explicações sobre o `CONVERT`

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @data datetime=GetDate()

SELECT concat(YEAR(@data),'-',MONTH(@data),'-',DAY(@data)) As data_convertida
```

A função Concat é válida apenas a partir do SQL Server 2012 caso nao tenha esse SQL use a que se segue

```
SELECT cast(YEAR(@data) as varchar(4))+'-'+cast(MONTH(@data)  as varchar(2))+'-'+cast(DAY(@data) as varchar(4)) As data_convertida
```

**Nota:** Veja que neste caso usei uma variável do tipo datetime
Usando as funcções DAY(), MONTH() e YEAR(), o SQL automaticamente sabe onde encontrar os valores para cada um dos valores que pede na função.

Que tipo de variável/dado você está tentado converter para esse formato

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '14/12/2015 00:00:00', 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **EDITADO:** Depois de alguns testes realizados observei que a função `CONVERT` só irá funcionar se a variável que será formatada/convertida for do tipo `Date`.

Utilize a função [CONVERT(tipo_dado(tamanho), variável, estilo)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp).

O primeiro parâmetro é o tipo de dado que será formatado, o segundo parâmetro é a variável que irá converter e o terceiro é o código do padrão que deseja, nesse caso 111 corresponde a `yyyy/mm/dd`.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111);
```

Comment: Parece que não. Eu testei esse comando e ele traz no formato dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @AlbertoCláudioMandlate realmente não estava funcionando, meu erro estava em utilizar `string` para converter. A variável original deve ser do tipo `Date`, então irá funcionar.

Comment: @Lilloh fiz uma pequena alteração na resposta, confere novamente, por gentileza.

Comment: Viva, fiz o teste alterando o tipo de dados para Date e realmente funcionou. Parece-me também uma boa dica

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

> SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)

Ou isso

> select date(ColumnName) from tablename

Comment: Pro pessoal que negativou, seria bacana um comentário. =/

Comment: O código 103 corresponde a `dd/mm/yyyy`. Acredito que seja esse o motivo de negativarem as respostas sua e do @PauloHDSousa

Comment: Dá nada não @PedroCamaraJunior. Sempre vai existir isso. Nem sempre temos tempo de uma resposta todo enfeitada, o tempo é curto. Mas ajudo como posso.

Comment: Obrigado @PedroCamaraJunior

Answer (score -1):

no MYSQL você pode usar o DATE_FORMAT()